# Querying Joined Tables

Tags: mysql

My application is a loans processing platform

For this question, let us assume there are 5 tables. Below is a brief description of what these tables do, and the current number of records.

- **loans** - holds the loans data - 1.5m records
- **clients** - holds client name etc - 500k records
- **client_coms** - client phone and email records - 1.5m records
- **client_addresses** - client address records - 550k records
- **clients_banks** - client bank account data - 520k records

I have added create table queries and some test data at the bottom of the question.

My problem is geting a query to run efficiently when searching for values held in joined tables.

**Hypothetical Scenario:**

- I have a client with ID 12516
- There are 4 records in the client _coms table related to this client, one of which has the value tony@findme.com
- I need to search for a record in the loans table which has a client with the email address of tony@findme.com
- I am currently joining the clients_coms table to the loans table ON client_id, and then grouping by client_id
- This is taking quite a while to run especially f there are multiple criteria in the where clause

**Example query:**

```
SELECT l.*, c.*
FROM loans l
LEFT JOIN clients c ON l.client_id = c.client_id
LEFT JOIN clients_coms com ON l.client_id = com.client_id
LEFT JOIN clients_addresses ad ON l.client_id = ad.client_id
LEFT JOIN clients_emp emp ON l.client_id = emp.client_id
LEFT JOIN clients_banks bank ON l.client_id = bank.client_id
WHERE com.value = 'llyamjamie@aol.com'
AND bank.sort_code = '309374'
GROUP BY l.loan_id
```

Is there any way to do this more efficiantly, and preferably without the GROUP BY loan_id

**Create Table Queries and Test Data**

```
    SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
    SET time_zone = "+00:00";

    CREATE TABLE `clients` (
      `client_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `username` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
      `password` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
      `clientref` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
      `title_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `fname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
      `mname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
      `lname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
      `dob` date DEFAULT NULL,
      `dependants` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
      `marital_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `status_difficulty_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
      `blacklisted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `market_consent` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `market_broker` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `created` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    INSERT INTO `clients` (`client_id`, `username`, `password`, `clientref`, `title_id`, `fname`, `mname`, `lname`, `dob`, `dependants`, `marital_id`, `status_difficulty_id`, `blacklisted`, `market_consent`, `market_broker`, `created`) VALUES
    (12516, 'tony@strat55yinternet.com', 'e8fec09af5441b940b200a0df09039db', 'Yamantaka108!', 1, 'Anthony', NULL, 'Simmons', '1961-11-26', 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, '2017-02-27 01:08:26'),
    (12517, 'trythis@ungdfgdfg.co.uk', '0cef1fb10f60529028a71f58e54ed07b', 'Password1!', 1, 'testme', NULL, 'testmeagain', '1983-09-19', 0, 3, 1, 0, 1, 0, '2017-04-21 08:59:16'),
    (12518, 'teddy.highlander@stradfgdfnternet.com', 'e8fec09af5441b940b200a0df09039db', 'Yamantaka108!', 1, 'Teddy', NULL, 'Highlander', '1990-01-01', 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, '2017-04-21 09:37:08'),
    (12519, 'terry.v@stradfgyinternet.com', 'e8fec09af5441b940b200a0df09039db', 'Yamantaka108!', 1, 'Terry', NULL, 'Vanerslat', '1990-01-01', 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, '2017-04-21 09:42:53'),
    (12520, 'testybanker@stratedfgets.com', 'e8fec09af5441b940b200a0df09039db', 'Yamantaka108!', 1, 'Testy', NULL, 'Banker', '1990-01-01', 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, '2017-04-21 19:17:29'),
    (12521, 'teddy.kruger@stradfgrnet.com', 'e8fec09af5441b940b200a0df09039db', 'Yamantaka108!', 1, 'teddy', NULL, 'kruger', '1995-07-12', 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, '2017-05-01 08:23:04'),
    (12522, 'test123@test.com', '0cef1fb10f60529028a71f58e54ed07b', 'Password1!', 1, 'wptest', NULL, 'wptest', '1990-01-01', 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, '2017-05-02 16:51:06'),
    (12523, 'test123@undfggk.co.uk', '0cef1fb10f60529028a71f58e54ed07b', 'Password1!', 1, 'wptest', NULL, 'wptest', '1980-01-01', 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, '2017-05-08 09:46:24'),
    (12524, '43201at78285n316xl@udgfdfgdf.co.uk', '16125873728ecaa5663548acd8708dc1', 'Digitalis1!', 1, 'wptester', NULL, 'wptester', '1980-01-01', 0, 3, 1, 0, 1, 1, '2017-05-08 10:09:48'),
    (12525, 'test@test.com', '7b91953d6f7ace4bd58f5e27b92129b2', 'M4ll1ng$', 2, 'test', NULL, 'test', '1988-03-15', 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, '2017-05-12 10:20:18'),
    (12526, 'terry@terry.com', 'e8fec09af5441b940b200a0df09039db', 'Yamantaka108!', 1, 'Terry', NULL, 'Vanguard', '1998-02-03', 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, '2017-05-12 21:51:34'),
    (12527, 'tony@tester.com', 'f44de07db359724e8be77b679d648261', 'C&e3zCyl', 2, 'Tony', NULL, 'Tester', '1998-06-16', 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, '2017-05-12 22:01:57'),
    (12528, 'terry@tester.com', 'e8fec09af5441b940b200a0df09039db', 'Yamantaka108!', 2, 'Terry', NULL, 'Tester', '1998-10-20', 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, '2017-05-12 22:08:22'),
    (12529, 'info@myemail.com', 'e8fec09af5441b940b200a0df09039db', 'Yamantaka108!', 1, 'Anthony', NULL, 'Simmons', '1980-02-05', 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, '2017-05-12 23:14:28'),
    (12530, 'sgmudfgrray@lidfgve.co.uk', '8889c4ff30a036e69af92c00e7381f9b', 'Trepalle$666', 1, 'Steve', NULL, 'Murray', '1966-02-07', 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, '2017-05-16 10:05:04'),
    (12533, 'mbucgper@undfgck.co.uk', '7b91953d6f7ace4bd58f5e27b92129b2', 'M4ll1ng$', 1, 'Matt', NULL, 'Smith', '1970-01-27', 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, '2017-05-17 10:55:23'),
    (12534, '1@unerteruck.co.uk', '7b91953d6f7ace4bd58f5e27b92129b2', 'M4ll1ng$', 1, 'Jacob', NULL, 'Matthews', '1960-05-31', 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, '2017-05-17 15:17:56'),
    (12535, '2@uncrteterk.co.uk', '7b91953d6f7ace4bd58f5e27b92129b2', 'M4ll1ng$', 4, 'Jess', NULL, 'Brown', '1960-06-09', 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, '2017-05-17 15:45:02'),
    (12536, 'test@straerttester.com', 'e8fec09af5441b940b200a0df09039db', 'Yamantaka108!', 1, 'Test', NULL, 'Testerly', '1997-09-22', 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, '2017-05-24 05:13:46'),
    (12539, 'test@test34324.com', '5db95e2186901ec55d959bc0db190bc8', 'RfsBMZ_w', 1, 'Matt', NULL, 'smith', '1960-02-02', 4, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, '2017-09-25 07:33:57'),
    (12540, 'test@gmail.com', 'a42316cf2aedfa853893628eb74bcfb4', 'PF8r!W&R', 4, 'Ema', NULL, 'Gupta', '1920-02-03', 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, '2017-10-09 11:20:00'),
    (12542, 'rgupta@unertetck.com', 'f925916e2754e5e03f75dd58a5733251', 'Test@123', 3, 'Ruchi  ', NULL, 'Gupta', '1983-01-01', 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, '2017-10-09 13:09:49');


    CREATE TABLE `clients_addresses` (
      `client_address_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `client_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `house_number` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
      `house_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
      `street` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
      `city` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
      `county` varchar(70) DEFAULT NULL,
      `postcode` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
      `home_status_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `movein_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
      `current` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
      `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


    INSERT INTO `clients_addresses` (`client_address_id`, `client_id`, `house_number`, `house_name`, `street`, `city`, `county`, `postcode`, `home_status_id`, `movein_date`, `current`, `created`) VALUES
    (590, 12516, '1', 'Paddock House', 'Merrow Street', 'Guildford', NULL, 'GU47AG', 1, '2000-02-01', 1, '2017-02-27 01:09:17'),
    (591, 12519, '45', 'willow tree', 'smith street', 'southfields', NULL, 'Sw185dj', 1, '2000-01-01', 1, '2017-04-21 09:43:44'),
    (592, 12520, '44', 'Patcick house', 'pastel St', 'Guildford', NULL, 'Gu47ag', 1, '1998-01-01', 1, '2017-04-21 19:18:16'),
    (593, 12521, '1', 'Haybarn House', 'Guildford Rd', 'Guildford', NULL, 'GU12QL', 1, '1998-01-01', 1, '2017-05-01 08:23:43'),
    (594, 12522, '221b Baker Street', '', 'Baker Street', 'bromley', NULL, 'NW1 6XE', 1, '2005-12-01', 1, '2017-05-02 16:52:46'),
    (595, 12523, '5-6', '', 'Matthews Street', 'Rugby', NULL, 'CV21 3BY', 1, '2001-01-01', 1, '2017-05-08 09:47:58'),
    (596, 12524, '21', '', 'Henry Street', 'Stratford', NULL, 'CV37 6QW', 1, '2000-12-01', 1, '2017-05-08 10:11:16'),
    (597, 12525, '707', '', 'Churchill Way', 'Westerham', NULL, 'TN16 3BN', 1, '2008-04-01', 1, '2017-05-12 10:21:00'),
    (598, 12528, '58', '', 'High Path Road', 'Guildford', NULL, 'GU1 2QL', 1, '2017-01-01', 1, '2017-05-12 22:11:46'),
    (599, 12528, '', '2 Paddock House', 'Merrow Street', 'Guildford', NULL, 'GU4 7AG', 2, '2016-01-01', 0, '2017-05-12 22:11:46'),
    (600, 12529, '3', 'Britannia House', 'Caerphilly Business Park', 'Caerphilly', NULL, 'CF83 3GG', 2, '2012-02-01', 1, '2017-05-12 23:14:46'),
    (601, 12530, '1', 'Cronks Farm', 'Hampstead Lane', 'Maidstone', NULL, 'ME185HN', 1, '2004-04-01', 1, '2017-05-16 10:06:27'),
    (604, 12542, '707', '', 'Biggnin Hill', 'westerham', NULL, 'TN16 3BN', 1, '2011-01-01', 1, '2017-10-09 13:10:42');


    CREATE TABLE `clients_banks` (
      `client_bank_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `client_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `bank_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `sort_code` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
      `account` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
      `bank_name` varchar(70) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Returned by AFD API',
      `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
      `created` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


    INSERT INTO `clients_banks` (`client_bank_id`, `client_id`, `bank_id`, `sort_code`, `account`, `bank_name`, `active`, `created`) VALUES
    (544, 12516, 3, '309374', '03522844', 'Lloyds Bank PLC', 0, '2017-02-27 01:11:47'),
    (551, 12516, 3, '301641', '60722260', 'Lloyds International', 1, '2017-02-28 06:16:41'),
    (552, 12516, 3, '309384', '03544844', 'Lloyds Bank PLC', 0, '2017-02-28 06:17:57'),
    (553, 12519, 3, '804378', '03555844', 'Lloyds Bank PLC', 1, '2017-04-21 09:52:12'),
    (554, 12520, 3, '309355', '03555844', 'Lloyds Bank PLC', 1, '2017-04-21 19:21:09'),
    (555, 12521, 3, '802374', '03566844', 'Lloyds Bank PLC', 1, '2017-05-01 08:37:04'),
    (556, 12523, 3, '602044', '00000000', 'Nat West Bank PLC', 1, '2017-05-08 09:54:26'),
    (557, 12524, 3, '902046', '00000000', 'Nat West Bank PLC', 1, '2017-05-08 10:15:03'),
    (558, 12525, 5, '602044', '00000000', 'Nat West Bank PLC', 1, '2017-05-12 11:42:42'),
    (559, 12528, 3, '309674', '03577844', 'Lloyds Bank PLC', 1, '2017-05-12 22:15:12'),
    (560, 12529, 3, '399379', '03588844', 'Lloyds Bank PLC', 0, '2017-05-12 23:18:40'),
    (561, 12529, 3, '909374', '03511844', 'Lloyds Bank PLC', 1, '2017-05-12 23:25:53');


    CREATE TABLE `clients_coms` (
      `client_coms_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `client_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `coms_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `value` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
      `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
      `main` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
      `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

    INSERT INTO `clients_coms` (`client_coms_id`, `client_id`, `coms_id`, `value`, `active`, `main`, `user_id`, `created`) VALUES
    (1685, 12516, 1, 'tony@findme.com', 0, 0, 0, '2017-02-27 01:08:26'),
    (1685, 12516, 1, 'tony@findmeagain.com', 0, 0, 0, '2017-02-27 01:08:26'),
    (1686, 12516, 2, '07081447123', 1, 1, 0, '2017-02-27 01:08:26'),
    (1687, 12516, 3, '02081447423', 1, 1, 0, '2017-02-27 01:08:26'),
    (1688, 12516, 4, '02081447128', 1, 1, 0, '2017-02-27 01:10:08'),
    (1689, 12517, 1, 'trythis@sdfsdfsdf.co.uk', 0, 1, 0, '2017-04-21 08:59:16'),
    (1690, 12517, 2, '07702419620', 0, 1, 0, '2017-04-21 08:59:16'),
    (1691, 12517, 3, '07702019420', 0, 1, 0, '2017-04-21 08:59:16'),
    (1692, 12518, 1, 'teddy.highlander@sdfsdfsdf.com', 1, 1, 0, '2017-04-21 09:37:08'),
    (1693, 12518, 2, '07232344566', 1, 1, 0, '2017-04-21 09:37:08'),
    (1694, 12518, 3, '02928848888', 1, 1, 0, '2017-04-21 09:37:08'),
    (1695, 12519, 1, 'terry.v@sdfsdfsd.com', 1, 1, 0, '2017-04-21 09:42:53'),
    (1696, 12519, 2, '07332242323', 1, 1, 0, '2017-04-21 09:42:53'),
    (1697, 12519, 3, '02048787656', 1, 1, 0, '2017-04-21 09:42:53'),
    (1698, 12519, 4, '02089448776', 1, 1, 0, '2017-04-21 09:46:45'),
    (1699, 12520, 1, 'testybanker@sdfsd.com', 1, 1, 0, '2017-04-21 19:17:29'),
    (1700, 12520, 2, '07224232345', 1, 1, 0, '2017-04-21 19:17:29'),
    (1701, 12520, 3, '02083438383', 1, 1, 0, '2017-04-21 19:17:29'),
    (1702, 12520, 4, '02082384282', 1, 1, 0, '2017-04-21 19:19:00'),
    (1703, 12516, 1, 'tday@sdfsdfsdfs.co.uk', 1, 1, 18, '2017-04-24 08:57:18'),
    (1704, 12521, 1, 'teddy.kruger@sdfsdfsd.com', 1, 1, 0, '2017-05-01 08:23:04'),
    (1705, 12521, 2, '07665865665', 1, 1, 0, '2017-05-01 08:23:04'),
    (1706, 12521, 3, '02087278888', 1, 1, 0, '2017-05-01 08:23:04'),
    (1707, 12521, 4, '02098828722', 1, 1, 0, '2017-05-01 08:24:26'),
    (1708, 12522, 1, 'test123@test.com', 1, 1, 0, '2017-05-02 16:51:06'),
    (1709, 12522, 2, '07507254489', 1, 1, 0, '2017-05-02 16:51:06'),
    (1710, 12522, 3, '07207254489', 1, 1, 0, '2017-05-02 16:51:06'),
    (1711, 12522, 4, '01522904210', 1, 1, 0, '2017-05-02 16:55:13'),
    (1712, 12523, 1, 'test123@fdgdfg.co.uk', 1, 1, 0, '2017-05-08 09:46:24'),
    (1713, 12523, 2, '07494254592', 1, 1, 0, '2017-05-08 09:46:24'),
    (1714, 12523, 3, '07494254592', 1, 1, 0, '2017-05-08 09:46:24'),
    (1715, 12523, 4, '01980512110', 1, 1, 0, '2017-05-08 09:49:29'),
    (1716, 12524, 1, '43201at78285n316xl@undgdfck.co.uk', 1, 1, 0, '2017-05-08 10:09:48'),
    (1717, 12524, 2, '07494854590', 1, 1, 0, '2017-05-08 10:09:48'),
    (1718, 12524, 3, '01420414510', 1, 1, 0, '2017-05-08 10:09:48'),
    (1719, 12524, 4, '07494854592', 1, 1, 0, '2017-05-08 10:13:02'),
    (1720, 12525, 1, 'test@test.com', 1, 1, 0, '2017-05-12 10:20:18'),
    (1721, 12525, 2, '07343242342', 1, 1, 0, '2017-05-12 10:20:18'),
    (1722, 12525, 3, '01731123456', 1, 1, 0, '2017-05-12 10:20:18'),
    (1723, 12525, 4, '01734123456', 1, 1, 0, '2017-05-12 10:21:49'),
    (1724, 12526, 1, 'terry@terry.com', 1, 1, 0, '2017-05-12 21:51:34'),
    (1725, 12526, 2, '07123333333', 1, 1, 0, '2017-05-12 21:51:34'),
    (1726, 12526, 3, '03034334343', 1, 1, 0, '2017-05-12 21:51:34'),
    (1727, 12527, 1, 'tony@tester.com', 1, 0, 0, '2017-05-12 22:01:57'),
    (1728, 12527, 2, '07544444444', 1, 1, 0, '2017-05-12 22:01:57'),
    (1729, 12527, 3, '02086767676', 1, 1, 0, '2017-05-12 22:01:57'),
    (1730, 12528, 1, 'terry@tester.com', 1, 1, 0, '2017-05-12 22:08:22'),
    (1731, 12528, 2, '07332232222', 1, 1, 0, '2017-05-12 22:08:22'),
    (1732, 12528, 3, '02098888888', 1, 1, 0, '2017-05-12 22:08:22'),
    (1733, 12528, 4, '02089992929', 1, 1, 0, '2017-05-12 22:13:02'),
    (1734, 12529, 1, 'info@myemail.com', 1, 1, 0, '2017-05-12 23:14:28'),
    (1735, 12529, 2, '07086667656', 1, 1, 0, '2017-05-12 23:14:28'),
    (1736, 12529, 3, '02098887878', 1, 1, 0, '2017-05-12 23:14:28'),
    (1737, 12529, 4, '02087776767', 1, 1, 0, '2017-05-12 23:15:17'),
    (1738, 12530, 1, 'sgmudfgrray@live.co.uk', 1, 1, 0, '2017-05-16 10:05:04'),
    (1739, 12530, 2, '07771755011', 1, 1, 0, '2017-05-16 10:05:04'),
    (1740, 12530, 3, '01622817656', 1, 1, 0, '2017-05-16 10:05:04'),
    (1741, 12530, 4, '02037475718', 1, 1, 0, '2017-05-16 10:07:43'),
    (1748, 12533, 1, 'mbudfgper@undfgdk.co.uk', 1, 1, 0, '2017-05-17 10:55:23'),
    (1749, 12533, 2, '07000123456', 1, 1, 0, '2017-05-17 10:55:23'),
    (1750, 12533, 3, '02030000000', 1, 1, 0, '2017-05-17 10:55:23'),
    (1751, 12534, 1, '1@uncdfgdfgck.co.uk', 1, 1, 0, '2017-05-17 15:17:56'),
    (1752, 12534, 2, '07000000000', 1, 1, 0, '2017-05-17 15:17:56'),
    (1753, 12534, 3, '02000000000', 1, 1, 0, '2017-05-17 15:17:56'),
    (1754, 12535, 1, '2@uncldfgdfk.co.uk', 1, 1, 0, '2017-05-17 15:45:02'),
    (1755, 12535, 2, '07000000001', 1, 1, 0, '2017-05-17 15:45:02'),
    (1756, 12535, 3, '02030000001', 1, 1, 0, '2017-05-17 15:45:02'),
    (1757, 12536, 1, 'test@stra890tedfgster.com', 1, 1, 0, '2017-05-24 05:13:46'),
    (1758, 12536, 2, '07332232277', 1, 1, 0, '2017-05-24 05:13:46'),
    (1759, 12536, 3, '02998879888', 1, 1, 0, '2017-05-24 05:13:46'),
    (1760, 12539, 1, 'test@test34324.com', 1, 1, 0, '2017-09-25 07:33:58'),
    (1763, 12540, 1, 'test@gmail.com', 1, 1, 0, '2017-10-09 11:20:00'),
    (1764, 12540, 2, '07123456789', 1, 1, 0, '2017-10-09 11:20:00'),
    (1765, 12540, 3, '01123456789', 1, 1, 0, '2017-10-09 11:20:00'),
    (1766, 12540, 4, '01234567895', 1, 1, 0, '2017-10-09 11:31:23'),
    (1770, 12540, 1, 'gargruchi12@gmail.com', 0, 0, 30, '2017-10-09 13:07:24'),
    (1771, 12542, 1, 'rgupta@uddfgdfgk.com', 1, 1, 0, '2017-10-09 13:09:49'),
    (1772, 12542, 2, '07507245489', 1, 1, 0, '2017-10-09 13:09:49'),
    (1773, 12542, 3, '01282560110', 1, 1, 0, '2017-10-09 13:09:49'),
    (1774, 12542, 4, '01282560110', 1, 1, 0, '2017-10-09 13:11:48'),
    (1775, 12542, 4, '01324564564', 1, 1, 0, '2017-10-09 13:14:34'),
    (1776, 12527, 1, 'rob@nedgfdfgdls.co.uk', 1, 1, 31, '2017-10-12 09:42:13');


    CREATE TABLE `loans` (
      `loan_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `client_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
      `amount` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
      `interest_percent` decimal(7,2) DEFAULT '0.00' COMMENT 'Daily Interest Rate',
      `instalments` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
      `fraud_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
      `code` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
      `code_sent` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `signed` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
      `signed_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
      `approved_amount` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
      `approved_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `rtd` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `rtd_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      `deposited_amount` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
      `deposited_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
      `depsosited_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `due_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
      `assigned_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
      `content_message_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `balance` decimal(7,2) DEFAULT NULL,
      `payout` decimal(7,2) DEFAULT NULL,
      `repaid` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `repaid_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
      `writeoff` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `writeoff_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
      `writeoff_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `apr` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
      `sweep` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
      `test` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `ip` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
      `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    INSERT INTO `loans` (`loan_id`, `client_id`, `product_id`, `amount`, `interest_percent`, `instalments`, `fraud_id`, `code`, `code_sent`, `signed`, `signed_date`, `approved_amount`, `approved_user_id`, `rtd`, `rtd_date`, `deposited_amount`, `deposited_date`, `depsosited_user_id`, `due_date`, `assigned_user_id`, `content_message_id`, `balance`, `payout`, `repaid`, `repaid_date`, `writeoff`, `writeoff_date`, `writeoff_user_id`, `apr`, `sweep`, `test`, `ip`, `created`) VALUES
    (9549, 12516, 4, '200.00', '0.80', 6, 1, '7812', 0, 1, '2017-02-27', '200.00', 1, 0, NULL, '200.00', '2017-01-03', 1, NULL, 1, 4, '90.22', '90.22', 0, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, '1266.04', 1, 0, NULL, '2017-02-27 01:08:26'),
    (9550, 12517, 4, '100.00', '0.80', 6, 1, '7521', 0, 0, NULL, '0.00', NULL, 0, NULL, '0.00', NULL, NULL, NULL, 18, NULL, '0.00', NULL, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, 0, NULL, '2017-04-21 08:59:16'),
    (9551, 12518, 4, '100.00', '0.80', 6, 1, '7146', 0, 0, NULL, '0.00', NULL, 0, NULL, '0.00', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, 0, NULL, '2017-04-21 09:37:08'),
    (9552, 12519, 4, '100.00', '0.80', 6, 1, '9524', 0, 0, NULL, '0.00', 0, 0, NULL, '0.00', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 2, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, 0, NULL, '2017-04-21 09:42:53'),
    (9553, 12520, 1, '100.00', '0.80', 3, 1, '2597', 0, 0, NULL, '0.00', 0, 0, NULL, '0.00', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 2, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, 0, NULL, '2017-04-21 19:17:29'),
    (9554, 12521, 1, '100.00', '0.80', 3, 1, '8057', 0, 0, NULL, '0.00', 0, 0, NULL, '0.00', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 2, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, 0, NULL, '2017-05-01 08:23:04'),
    (9555, 12516, 4, '200.00', '0.80', 6, 1, '7812', 0, 1, '2017-03-27', '200.00', 1, 0, NULL, '200.00', '2017-02-03', 1, NULL, 1, 4, '508.80', NULL, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, '1266.04', 1, 0, NULL, '2017-03-27 00:08:26'),
    (9556, 12522, 1, '100.00', '0.80', 3, 1, '2976', 0, 0, NULL, '0.00', NULL, 0, NULL, '0.00', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, 0, NULL, '2017-05-02 16:51:06'),
    (9557, 12523, 1, '100.00', '0.80', 3, 1, '4366', 0, 0, NULL, '0.00', 0, 0, NULL, '0.00', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 2, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, 0, NULL, '2017-05-08 09:46:24'),
    (9558, 12524, 1, '100.00', '0.80', 3, 1, '9040', 0, 0, NULL, '100.00', 18, 0, NULL, '0.00', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 2, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, 0, NULL, '2017-05-08 10:09:48'),
    (9559, 12525, 1, '250.00', '0.80', 3, 1, '4416', 0, 0, NULL, '0.00', 0, 0, NULL, '0.00', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 2, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, 0, NULL, '2017-05-12 10:20:18'),
    (9560, 12526, 1, '175.00', '0.80', 3, 1, '2242', 0, 0, NULL, '0.00', NULL, 0, NULL, '0.00', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, 0, NULL, '2017-05-12 21:51:34'),
    (9561, 12527, 1, '100.00', '0.80', 3, 1, '2623', 0, 0, NULL, '0.00', NULL, 0, NULL, '0.00', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, 0, NULL, '2017-05-12 22:01:57'),
    (9562, 12528, 1, '100.00', '0.80', 3, 1, '4932', 1, 1, '2017-05-12', '100.00', 1, 1, '2017-05-13 05:14:06', '0.00', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 2, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, 0, NULL, '2017-05-12 22:08:22'),
    (9563, 12529, 1, '150.00', '0.80', 3, 1, '8136', 0, 0, NULL, '0.00', 0, 0, NULL, '0.00', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 2, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, 0, NULL, '2017-05-12 23:14:28'),
    (9564, 12530, 1, '350.00', '0.80', 3, 1, '2248', 0, 0, NULL, '0.00', 0, 0, NULL, '0.00', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 2, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, 0, NULL, '2017-05-16 10:05:04'),
    (9565, 12536, 1, '200.00', '0.80', 3, 1, '8079', 0, 0, NULL, '0.00', NULL, 0, NULL, '0.00', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, 0, NULL, '2017-05-24 05:13:46'),
    (9567, 12539, 1, '300.00', '0.80', 3, 1, '8223', 0, 0, NULL, '0.00', NULL, 0, NULL, '0.00', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, 0, NULL, '2017-09-25 07:33:58'),
    (9568, 12540, 1, '375.00', '0.80', 3, 1, '9123', 0, 0, NULL, '0.00', 0, 0, NULL, '0.00', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 2, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, 0, NULL, '2017-10-09 11:20:00'),
    (9570, 12542, 1, '100.00', '0.80', 3, 1, '4470', 0, 0, NULL, '0.00', NULL, 0, NULL, '0.00', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, 0, NULL, '2017-10-09 13:09:49');

    ALTER TABLE `clients`
      ADD PRIMARY KEY (`client_id`),
      ADD KEY `fname` (`fname`),
      ADD KEY `created` (`created`),
      ADD KEY `lname` (`lname`),
      ADD KEY `title_id` (`title_id`),
      ADD KEY `username` (`username`),
      ADD KEY `clientref` (`clientref`),
      ADD KEY `dob` (`dob`),
      ADD KEY `market_consent` (`market_consent`),
      ADD KEY `blacklisted` (`blacklisted`),
      ADD KEY `market_broker` (`market_broker`),
      ADD KEY `marital_id` (`marital_id`),
      ADD KEY `status_difficulty_id` (`status_difficulty_id`);

    ALTER TABLE `clients_addresses`
      ADD PRIMARY KEY (`client_address_id`),
      ADD KEY `created` (`created`),
      ADD KEY `postcode` (`postcode`),
      ADD KEY `client_id` (`client_id`),
      ADD KEY `move_in_date` (`movein_date`),
      ADD KEY `current` (`current`),
      ADD KEY `home_status_id` (`home_status_id`);

    ALTER TABLE `clients_banks`
      ADD PRIMARY KEY (`client_bank_id`),
      ADD KEY `created` (`created`),
      ADD KEY `sort_code` (`sort_code`),
      ADD KEY `bank_id` (`bank_id`),
      ADD KEY `client_id` (`client_id`),
      ADD KEY `active` (`active`);

    ALTER TABLE `clients_coms`
      ADD PRIMARY KEY (`client_coms_id`),
      ADD KEY `client_id` (`client_id`),
      ADD KEY `value` (`value`),
      ADD KEY `active` (`active`),
      ADD KEY `created` (`created`),
      ADD KEY `coms_id` (`coms_id`),
      ADD KEY `primary_2` (`main`),
      ADD KEY `user_id` (`user_id`);

    ALTER TABLE `loans`
      ADD PRIMARY KEY (`loan_id`),
      ADD KEY `client_id` (`client_id`),
      ADD KEY `product_id` (`product_id`),
      ADD KEY `depsoited_user_id` (`depsosited_user_id`),
      ADD KEY `deposited_date` (`deposited_date`),
      ADD KEY `approved_user_id` (`approved_user_id`),
      ADD KEY `deposited_amount` (`deposited_amount`),
      ADD KEY `created` (`created`),
      ADD KEY `repaid` (`repaid`),
      ADD KEY `repaid_date` (`repaid_date`),
      ADD KEY `sweep` (`sweep`),
      ADD KEY `due_date` (`due_date`),
      ADD KEY `ip` (`ip`),
      ADD KEY `signed` (`signed`),
      ADD KEY `signed_date` (`signed_date`),
      ADD KEY `fraud_id` (`fraud_id`),
      ADD KEY `assigned_user_id` (`assigned_user_id`),
      ADD KEY `code_sent` (`code_sent`),
      ADD KEY `test` (`test`),
      ADD KEY `content_message_id` (`content_message_id`),
      ADD KEY `rtd` (`rtd`),
      ADD KEY `rtd_date` (`rtd_date`),
      ADD KEY `rtd_2` (`rtd`,`deposited_amount`),
      ADD KEY `writeoff` (`writeoff`),
      ADD KEY `writeoff_date` (`writeoff_date`),
      ADD KEY `payout` (`payout`),
      ADD KEY `balance` (`balance`),
      ADD KEY `writeoff_user_id` (`writeoff_user_id`);


    ALTER TABLE `clients`
      MODIFY `client_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=12543;

    ALTER TABLE `clients_addresses`
      MODIFY `client_address_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=605;

    ALTER TABLE `clients_banks`
      MODIFY `client_bank_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=564;

    ALTER TABLE `clients_coms`
      MODIFY `client_coms_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=1777;

    ALTER TABLE `loans`
      MODIFY `loan_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=9571;

    ALTER TABLE `clients_addresses`
      ADD CONSTRAINT `clients_addresses_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`client_id`) REFERENCES `clients` (`client_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,

    ALTER TABLE `clients_banks`
      ADD CONSTRAINT `clients_banks_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`client_id`) REFERENCES `clients` (`client_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

    ALTER TABLE `clients_coms`
      ADD CONSTRAINT `clients_coms_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`client_id`) REFERENCES `clients` (`client_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,

    ALTER TABLE `loans`
      ADD CONSTRAINT `loans_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`client_id`) REFERENCES `clients` (`client_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
```

Comment: Understand the difference between `LEFT JOIN` and  just `JOIN` (sometimes called `INNER JOIN`). `LEFT JOIN` will be much slower.  You should also consider doing this in multiple queries. You are missing data you may want from tables that have multiple matches with the `GROUP BY`. An example of the output you want would really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In standard SQL it is impossible to group by a single column and still still output ever column from 2 tables (`SELECT l.*, c.*`). [MySQL contains a non-standard "extension"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) which permits your query to run without an error message, but the truth is you should not rely on that extension. So you will need to adopt a more stringent approach to any query using `group by`.

You have also used a series of `LEFT JOINS` and the very reason we use that type of join is so that an unmatched row in the main table can still be returned. In other words, for each left joined table that table's columns can all be NULL. However your where clause overrides this possibility be insisting that `com.value = 'llyamjamie@aol.com'` or that `bank.sort_code = '309374'`. If you want more efficiency don't use left joins with those tables.

It appears as if you want one query to do almost anything, and at the same time be at peak efficiency. However these 2 objectives (flexibility and efficiency) compete.

You may find the following style of query more efficient yet sufficiently flexible. I don't know how you are building your queries, but I presume you have set of parameters, so below I just have some placeholders for whatever you might be using.

```
select l.*, c.* ## but specify the columns you actually need
from Loans l
inner join clients c ON l.client_id = c.client_id
where l.client_id IN (
   select client_id
   from clients where @clients is not null
   union all
   select client_id
   from clients_coms where clients_coms.value = 'llyamjamie@aol.com'
   union all
   select client_id
   from clients_addresses where @clients_addresses is not null
   union all
   select client_id
   from clients_emp where @clients_emp is not null
   union all
   select client_id
   from clients_banks where clients_banks.sort_code = '309374'
  )
```

Ideally you would leave out the redundant parts of that query if you can. Note we do not need a group by through this approach. Please note however that this query has the effect ORs i.e.

```
`com.value = 'llyamjamie@aol.com'` OR `bank.sort_code = '309374'`
```

Then you will need to look at how you are indexing all those tables. Every column used into join tables will be indexed I trust. For other indexes you need to look at the explain plans, but the most frequently searched columns are candidates for indexing.

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks like selecting all table fields:

**Inefficient:**

1. It include all the records before it display the fields you wanted.
2. It making your query become too slow when the times comes you got a millions of data.
3. Performance problem.

**To Resolve:**

Just select specific fields that you need like:

Avoid using `Select *`

```
select a.f1,a.f2,b.f3,a.f4,b.f5 from
(select f1,f2,f4 from table1) as a
left join
(select f1, f3,f5 from table2) as b
on a.f1 = b.f1
```

as for me this is to be called table `query optimizing`

Off course All `indexes` of your tables are `done` and `created`.